# convert struct.unpack from python to objective-c?

Tags: python, objective-c, byte

I’m copying this python code from PDFMiner into objective-c:

```
            (name, tsum, offset, length) = struct.unpack('>4sLLL', fp.read(16))
```

This is what I have:

```
unsigned char characters[5];
    [stream getBytes:characters range:NSMakeRange(position, 4)];
    position+=4;
    characters[4] = 0;
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", characters];

    unsigned long tsum;
    [stream getBytes:&tsum range:NSMakeRange(position, 4)];
    position+=4;

    unsigned long offset;
    [stream getBytes:&offset range:NSMakeRange(position, 4)];
    position+=4;

    unsigned long length;
    [stream getBytes:&length range:NSMakeRange(position, 4)];
    position+=4;
```

The name is read correctly, but the tsum, offset, and length are read incorrectly. 
Any idea why this might not work?

Comment: I bet you expect invalid data type, maybe those longs aren't unsigned

Comment: Incorrectly in which way?

Comment: You might have to add `sum = ntohl(sum)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's padding bytes, but I'm not sure where. L stands for unsigned long so I doubt that's the problem